# How to get the variable from api and define in Nginx config file

Tags: django, nginx

I am using a GET api in which there is a parameter which is dynamic(a variable). I want to get that variable and give it to my Django server, but how do I tackle this in Nginx as I have a static api location.

The code where I am hitting the api:
Here waterQuantity is variable that will be provided by the user.

```
http.Response response =await http.get('http://192.168.0.110/openValveConst/$waterQuantity');
```

This is my Nginx config file right now:

```
location /openValveConst/ {
                    # why should i add / at the end 5000/ to make it work 
                proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8000/openValveConst/?format=json
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            }
```

Please suggest changes that I should do to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in a monolithic server(at least not with flexibility), and  even if you did somehow you might want to reload the config and restart nginx on-the-fly which is again a new headache of using pexpect or subprocess.

Though you can try micro container like docker, where you can efficiently change the configuration via YML/JSON/docker files.

Bottom line is you can have a flask project API (or django whichever you prefer) which get the config from the API(or even you can use cURL if it is not hard and fast to use python project as API caller) and once you get the updated config you update the docker file and put a new build with updated config, I would personally prefer to use micro-containers for such dynamic usage.

Comment: Thank you good sir for the suggestion, I will try and implement this, but this is kind of an urgent task that has to completed asap and I don't have much knowledge about micro containers like docker. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but since every request that begins with `openValveConst/` will be sent to your django application, you only need to specify a route in your django app that matches the query:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # other routes ...
    path('openValveConst/<int:waterQuantity>/', your_view)
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in that case what would I write in the proxy_pass attribute of the Nginx config file as there should be a variable. eg:  proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8000/openValveConst/some_value/?format=json. what will go in the place of some_value??. Appreciate the help.

Comment: You don't need to write anything there, your `/openValveConst/` in nginx configuration assumes that requests made to endpoint starting with `/openValveConst/` will be redirected to django